# Capybara Fires Test Before JS Finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I have a capybara test that checks to see if a class is found on the page. The class allows the user to view a sidebar. Here is the test below.

```
feature 'Lesson Sidebar', js: true do
  before do
    visit course_lesson_path
  end
  context 'persists the lesson sidebar display' do
    before do
      find('#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2').trigger('click')
    end

    scenario do
      expect(page).to have_selector('.lesson-page__sidebar--expanded', visible: false)
    end
  end
end
```

The JS code simply tacks on the class to the sidebar element when `#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2` is clicked. The code is within a document ready call.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lesson-subnav__heading').on("mousedown", "#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2", function (e) {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('lesson-page__sidebar--expanded')
  })
})
```

Here is the error response I received.

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
  Unable to find css "#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2"
```

This is my problem. The test will randomly fail. Not only for this test but for other tests within this page. My assumption is that the test is running before the JS has a chance to finish which is why the test fails sometimes. How do I fix this so the test passes every time?

Comment: Don't you have to pass the test the js: true option

Comment: Code updated to reflect that. Issue occurs anyways.

Comment: What error does it fail with?

Comment: It's telling me the element can't be found.

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: The posting of the actual error shows that it's the find in the before block thats not finding the element, which means this has nothing do with the `wait_for_ajax` call or event handler binding.  If doing something like  `find('#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2', wait: 20).click` doesn't make the error go away, then you have an issue with your page loading (or you've mistyped the selector) although I would not expect that to create an intermittent failure.  Check your test logs for what requests were actually made and/or add

```
sleep 10
page.save_screenshot
```

before the find/click and look at the page to see if it's what you expect.  Another thing to check would be that you're showing your JS errors in your driver config (I assume your using poltergeist since most people who default to .trigger generally are)

Comment: Interesting. I removed the `wait_for_ajax` and increased the `default_max_wait_time` to 10 seconds but am still receiving the same error as posted in my answer.

Comment: @jason328 Did you try putting `sleep 3` before the click?

Comment: Uh -- so it's the actual find in the before block that's failing intermittently - not the expectation in the test? Then it has nothing at all to do with the ajax or event handler. Try   `find('#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2', wait: 20).click`  - If that still fails then you have an issue with page loading.  Are you sure this is an intermittent error?  Where are you doing your `visit ...` ?

Comment: Yes, I did. Also `visit` is there I just didn't include it for simplicity sake. Sorry about the confusion.

Comment: I tried `find('#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2', wait: 20).click` but am still receiving the same issue.

Comment: @jason328 I updated my answer based on the actual error message you posted.

Comment: @jason328 One other question -- when you say it fails randomly, do you really mean it works fine when it's the only test you run, but then fails when more than just one test is run?

Comment: What I mean is that the test fails randomly, either when it runs with other tests or when it runs by itself. There are other tests that fail with this same type of error, 'a missing element.' I've also saved browser screenshots of the failed tests and see that the sidebar isn't shown. This makes sense since the element that is clicked on is inside the sidebar. Thus, if the sidebar isn't shown, the element isn't shown either.

Comment: Are you sure the element is always `'#lesson-sidebar__lesson-2'`  -- is the '2' based on the id of the lesson which would change from test to test?

Comment: No, that element is always there, irregardless if the test fails. I should clarify. I just checked the browser screenshot and discovered that the lesson sidebar is shown, thus the element should be found by Capybara.

Comment: @jason328  Then the only thing left would be to do the save_screenshot (image) or save_page (raw html) after sleeping for a few seconds and see what is actually there.  The only reason that `find` would fail with a wait of 20 is if the element wasn't there (you say it is), it wasn't visible (then you couldn't click it anyway), or your page isn't actually loading.

Comment: I have fixed that test. It was due in part to faulty seed data. However the issue still occurs where the test runs before JS is complete. The solution that is working for me is `sleep(5)` but I feel like this is a nasty solution and many people appear against it.

Comment: @jason328 sleep(5) where?  If you mean at the beginning of the before block, then you need to find something that changes in your page once the JS is loaded/run -- is a class or data attribute added to the body/html element? --  and check for that instead of the sleep